# Phpdocx: How to duplicate a page in template

Tags: php, ms-word, phpdocx

I want to ask, is it possible working with a template, and duplicate a specific page in that template without using WordFragment or addExternalFile (I want the template to be 1 file only)?

As an example, I have 3 page, I want to duplicate (or repeating) page 2 for 4 times, so the result is that I have a 7 paged document with a second page repeating for 4 times? Is it possible to do it without WordFragment or addExternalFile? Because I want to make it easier to edit in the template.

My Phpdocx is a trial version.

What I have tried so far is using wordfragment, by using $wordfragment$ variable in document template (in second page), and do this in php:

```
$wf = new WordFragment($docx, 'document');

for($i = 0: $<4; $i++) {
    /*here I put a code to make a text and table in wordfragment (sorry it's too long to write it here, it's about 500 lines)*/
    $wf->addBreak(array('type'=>'page')); //it's to go to next page
} //so this loop will make 4 same pages with the content I want in that 500 lines of code.
$docx->replaceVariableByWordFragment(array('wordfragment'=>$wf), array('type'=>'block'));
```

Using a WordFragment like above is actually very powerfull, and it is have a very great result, but since it will be used by my user, and we always presume that the user is not good with code, so I cannot let the user to edit the code if he/she just want to edit the template, in example, if the user want to edit the table in template, in this code of mine, that user need to edit it in that 500 lines codes, and that's very not user friendly, what I wanted is to make it more simple, make the text and table in word (so the user could just edit it in there), and in the code I just need to repeat that page. Is it possible?

Oh and the other method, addExternalFile is actually quite good, but by using this, I need to have more than 1 template, in example, I need 3 document, named start.docx, content.docx, end.docx. With addExternalFile, I could just used it like this:

```
$wf = new WordFragment($docx, 'document');
$wf->addExternalFile(array('src'=>'start.docx'));
$wf->addBreak(array('type'=>'page'));

for($i=0;$i<4;$i++) { 
   $content = new CreateDocxFromTemplate('content.docx');
   /*here I put a code to replace all text and table variable in template*/
   $content->replaceVariableByText($variables, $parameter); //$variables and $parameter already included in my code
   $content->replaceTableVariable($table); //$table already included in my code
   $content->createDocx('newcontent.docx');
   $wf->addExternalFile(array('src'=>'newcontent.docx'));
   $wf->addBreak(array('type'=>'page'));
} //this loop will make 4 same page

$wf->addExternalFile(array('src'=>'end.docx');
$docx->replaceVariableByWordFragment(array('wordfragment'=>$wf), array('type'=>'block'));
```

With addExternalFile, I could write text, variables, and draw a table in document and not in wordfragment. It's quite user friendly, but the flaw is that this method need atleast 3 different document to be opened by user if they want to edit it. What I want is just 1 document, all text, variables, and tables are in document, and there's no text or table in php code. Is there any method to do this with phpDocx?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service, but we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How To Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please update your question with the code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve.

Comment: oh yeah I forgot to write it, sorry, I'll edit my question.

Comment: Okay I already put my source code, sorry for the inconvenience, I hope there any of you who could help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: Okay, I give up with phpdocx, so I changed to phpword and it simply can be done by using cloneBlock function in phpword.